# ¿Cómo desabilitar un input con javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

Estoy intentado desabilitar un input al seleccionar un check pero, o no me reconoce la función, o no sé lo que esté haciendo mal.

Este es mi código:

```js
function desabilitar()
{
    var rangoSinPrecio = document.getElementById('rangoSinPrecio').checked;
    var precio = document.getElementById('precio');
    if (rangoSinPrecio === true) {
        precio.disabled = true;
    } else if (rangoSinPrecio === false) {
        precio.disabled = false;
    }
}
```

```html
<input type="range" class="custom-range" id="precio" min="0" max="100000" value="0">
<input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="rangoSinPrecio">
```

Comment: Puedes omitir muchos pasos en tus ifs, pero el detalle es, ¿en que momento mandas llamar a `deshabilitar`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

necesitas algo así:

```js
let rangoSinPrecio = document.getElementById("rangoSinPrecio");
rangoSinPrecio.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    let precio = document.getElementById("precio");
    let checked = e.toElement.checked;

    if (checked) {
        precio.disabled = true;
    } else {
        precio.disabled = false;
    }
});
```

```html
<input type="range" class="custom-range" id="precio" min="0" max="100000" value="0">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="rangoSinPrecio">
```

Saludos.

Answer (score 3):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>JS - Disable inputs with checkboxes</title>

    <style type="text/css">
        .content {
            padding: 5%;
        }
        .content div {
            margin-top: 5%;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="content">
        <h1>JS - Disable inputs with checkboxes</h1>

        <form name="form">
            <div>
                <input type="text" id="input-1"/> Input 1
            </div>
            <div>
                <input type="number" id="input-2"/> Input 2
            </div>
            <div>
                <input type="checkbox" id="check-1"> Disable Input 1
            </div>
            <div>
                <input type="checkbox" id="check-2"> Disable Input 2
            </div>

            <hr>
            <div>
                <input type="button" id="restart" value="Restart">
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>

    <script>

        /**
         * Functions
         *
         */

        function $(element_id)
        {
            return document.getElementById(element_id);
        }
        function swapInputDisabled(element_id)
        {
            const state = $(element_id).disabled;
            $(element_id).disabled = ! state;
        }
        function disableInput(element_id)
        {
            $(element_id).disabled = false;
        }


        /**
         * Event listeners
         *
         */

        $('check-1').addEventListener("click", () => {
            swapInputDisabled('input-1');
        });
        $('check-2').addEventListener("click", () => {
            swapInputDisabled('input-2');
        });
        $('restart').addEventListener("click", () => {
            disableInput('input-1');
            disableInput('input-2');
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Debería alcanzar con hacer lo siguiente:

- Recupera en variables tanto al input de tipo `range` como al input de tipo `checkbox`
- Revisaremos en la variable que almacena al checkbox su evento click asignando a ella un listener a dicho evento
- En caso de que exista dicho evento pasamos a la función anónima la variable del input de tipo range y en su propiedad disabled la colocamos a true

**Ejemplo**

```html
    <input type="range" class="custom-range" id="precio" min="0" max="100000" value="0">
      <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="rangoSinPrecio">
    
    <script>
    let precio = document.getElementById("precio")
    let cajaChecada = document.getElementById("rangoSinPrecio")
    
    cajaChecada.addEventListener("click", () => {
      console.log(precio)
      precio.disabled = true
    })
    </script>
```

Ahora si deseas tener la posibilidad de habilitar y deshabilitar, entonces:

- En un condicional verifica si la propiedad disabled es true, en ese caso la deshabilitamos para poder mover la barra del input y en caso contrario impedimos dicho comportamiento

**Código**

```html
    <input type="range" class="custom-range" id="precio" min="0" max="100000" value="0">
      <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="rangoSinPrecio">
    
    <script>
    let precio = document.getElementById("precio")
    let cajaChecada = document.getElementById("rangoSinPrecio")
    
    cajaChecada.addEventListener("click", () => {
      if(precio.disabled) {
        precio.disabled = false
      } else {
        precio.disabled = true
      }
    })
    </script>
```

Comment: Creo que las validaciones dependen de si cajaChecada isChecked, en todo caso omites el if y puede usar `precio.disabled = cajaChecada.checked`